# Forum module for Sitecore 7.*

Tags: sitecore, forum, sitecore7, yetanotherforum, telligent

I'm building a website which requires forum integration to a Sitecore build - I've checked on the Sitecore website and they suggest YetAnotherForum and Telligent Community Integration Module. Both of these modules tho only support up till 6.4.1 and 6.4 respectively - I'm using Sitecore 7.0.

Logged a ticket with Sitecore and they came back with the following:

*We have no information about Forum modules that are compatible with Sitecore 7.1. I would recommend you to contact your regional office and check whether they could advise you something.*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**First of all Telligent supports Sitecore 7.**

[Reference link](http://telligent.com/support/telligent_evolution_platform/community/w/community7/35751.telligent-connect-for-sitecore-3-0-installation-and-configuration.aspx)

I have been working with Sitecore and Telligent Community integration from quite time and from my experience i have this opinion.

For deep integration it is quite a lot of work and requires much knowledge of both the product and costs will be high for licensing & deployment. But i can assure you that Telligent will work in Sitecore newer version also. However with higher costs you will get more rich functionality, Facebook like Activity Stream, and Apart from Forums it also has Blogs, Wikis, Media Gallery.

Telligent supports two kind of integrations:
 1. Side by Side Integration - In this Sitecore and Telligent both will be user facing.
 2. Integration mode - In this user will be mostly in Sitecore.

[Reference link](http://telligent.com/support/telligent_evolution_platform/community/w/community7/35750.generate-sitecore-urls.aspx)

If you are Sitecore Partner you will get trial license of Telligent. For details check 'Social Starter Kit' on Sitecore SDN site. Also there is video on YouTube regarding [Sitecore & Telligent Integration](http://youtube.com/watch?v=jn8Gfr8dTec) in Sitecore Virtual User Group community.

I have no experience on YAF module so can't suggest on that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install YAF integration module, https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/YAF_integration.aspx, i think it would run on Sitecore 7, since this module mainly integrate YAF with Sitecore security, i don't see why it should not run on Sitecore 7.

Answer (score 0):

The Telligent product was renamed, I suggest you take a look at http://www.zimbra.com/products/zimbra-community/sitecore-starter.html and contact them. I'm unaware of what version they're targeted at right now.